# Installing testlink on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have created an Amazon EC2 instance to host a testlink server with RHEL. I have successfully configured mysql client, Apache and PHP, but when I try to install it and create the DB, I'm unable to reach my RDS instance that will be used to host this Database. I also tried creating the DB manually, but when trying to log in I'm still unable to reach the RDS instance with the following error: "Connect to database testlink on Host xxxxxxx fails 
DBMS Error Message: 2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxxxxxxxxx' (13) "

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Have you checked the security group settings for the RDS to make sure your instance can reach it?

Comment: I have ensured that the AWS EC2 instance has access to the RDS through security group settings and still unable to reach it from testlink installation page

Comment: Can you `telnet url.of.the.rds 3306`?

Comment: That's strange. I can't telnet the RDS instance. I think it could be related to firewall policies in my company. I'll see if I can get that port opened and it should work. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: But now that I remember. I also tried to connect from my house yesterday and still was unable to connect.

Comment: What are your RDS security group rules?

Comment: It's configured to authorize the EC2 security group that I used for my AWS instance.

Comment: Well, hitting the DB from home/work isn't going to work, then.

Comment: You're totally right. I'll work on fixing this. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score -1):

This could related two issues

- You might not not added your web server IP to the security group in RDS.
- You might have set the publicly accessible option to NO and in that case you can only access the RDS if your web servers are in the same VPC.

Answer (score -2):

I've struggled with the very same trouble and finally found the answer.
Just disable SELinux.

Comment: Or you could configure SELinux to allow whatever it's currently denying.